# How would I be able to measure the current using this setup?

Tags: current, resistors, current-measurement, measurement

What ways can I measure the current as test points on a circuit?

Would I need to add a zero ohm resistor and solder the resistor for normal operation and desolder the resistor and then place my ammeter in parallel with the desoldered resistor pads?

Does this look correct from the image?

Thanks[image]

Comment: Or use a switch instead of the 0 ohm resistor, then you don’t need to unsolder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can solder in 0 ohm for normal use and remove the "resistor" when you want to measure the current.

Or you use a small *shunt resistor* (depending on your load conditions, e.g. 1 ohm). This will let you use the circuit normally with just a litte but of voltage drop over your resistor. The resistor has to be chosen to drop only so much voltage, that you circuit will still be functional under full load. Then you can just use a voltmeter to measure the voltage drop to calculate your current whenever you want, without having to remove the resistor.

With Ohm's Law and 1 ohm for example you have a voltage drop of (1 V/A).

Comment: Hello jusaca,Thanks for the answer. I would assume that there a a number of ways to do it but the zero own is probably the best no?

Comment: That completely depends on you needs. If you do not want to measure the current that often, that might be a good way. If you want to measure the current more often, then this seems like a lot of efford...

Comment: You could use a jumper instead of a zero ohm resistor that you can take out when you connect your current meter. A shunt and a permanently connected volt meter would enable you to monitor the current continuously.

Comment: The only problem with having a shunt resistor permanently in circuit is that there would be a small power loss and voltage loss.  Whether that’s acceptable depends on your requirements

Comment: Thanks yes I changed it so that it is a jumper instead since it will probably be easier in the long run and prevent destroying the resistor from soldering and desoldering.